# How to fix Ubuntu 20.04 bogus SSD high temperature notification at every boot?

Tags: ssd, notification, temperature

A notification that happens at every boot states, "Disk Problems Detected. A hard disk is likely to fail soon." Clicking on the notification brings up the additional information that the disk is an SK hynix SC308 SATA 256GB (92C/198F). The system is dual boot Ubuntu/Windows, with each OS residing on its own drive. The Hynix SSD is the Windows disk, located at sda(C:).

I rebooted to Windows and found that CPUID HWMonitor reports a temperature of 29C/84F.  Then, I opened the case and moved my fingers over the surface of the Hynix and found no hotspots. After temperature comparisons on several days, it seems that the reported Ubuntu temperature is constant, while the Windows temperature varies. Based on these observations, I concluded that it is a false alarm because of incorrect temperature reading by Ubuntu. I assume that a hardware error would show up in the Windows reading, too.

Due to my infrequent use of Ubuntu, my best estimate is that some change to it in Sept. or very early Oct. 2020 is causing the problem.

Comment: If your disk is failing S.M.A.R.T. then it's probably dying

Comment: In order to investigate the S.M.A.R.T. system further, I downloaded the "SK hynix Drive Manager" from the manufacturer's website. Unfortunately, it is available only for Windows. There was no sign of malfunction in the S.M.A.R.T. system data and it reported the SSD temperature as 30C.